# How define two superclass in the same java code?

Tags: java, android, class, sms

My project is use to receive SMS and display in a list.
Error occurs in following line of code

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main,str));
```

Due to ListActivity is not define in code below. However BroadcastReceiver required for method to receive SMS.

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
```

So, question is how to define both superclass in one java codes? Full java code is provided below:

```
    package net.eg.app;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";     
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";        
            }

            //---display in list---
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main,str));

            ListView listView = getListView();
            listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


            //---method is call when listitem is clicked---
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                //described method
            });
        }                         
    }


}
```

Comment: Java does not support multiple inheritance, if that's what you're asking. Make your class wrap the classes you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "define both superclass" you mean, extending more than one class then the simple answer is **NO**. Java does not support multiple inheritance. You should rethink your whole approach.

But you can do something like:

```
public class YourClass extends Class1 {

    private final Class2 class2Impl = new Class2() {
    // Class2 "view" of this class, this inner class
    // has access to all fields/methods of YourClass
    };

    public Class2 asClass2() { return class2Impl; }

    }
```

Also you can find more on multiple inheritance and "work-arounds" if you really needed. Just search on [Google](http://www.google.com).

Hope that helps. If that did not help at all, then my apologies for misunderstanding your question.

Comment: thanks, u did answer my question. but, i can't fully understand d codes u suggested. May i know what is class2Impl?   and why it needs   `public Class2 asClass2() {return class2Impl;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like 0gravity said precisely as;

```
public class SMSActivity extends ListActivity {
private SMSReceived mSmsReceiver;

//activity private variable to be manipulated by the sms receiver
private mSmsCount;


public SMSActivity(){
    mSmsReceiver = new SMSReceived();
}


private class SMSReceived extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //lets manipulate the SMSActivity's private member variable
        mSmsCount++;
    }
}
```

}

You are also facing the very common problem that ListActivity is highly inflexibly. The alternative solution is the just never use ListActivity.

Just use a normal activity, embed a ListView in the layout, and implement the ListAdapter in a private inner class. ListActivity is too rigid in layout and saves almost no code to be worth the hassle, it will save you countless times when you have to refactor into this approach anyway and its really not much extra code and is more readable.